# VB.NET Graphical overlay not lined up between computers

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, dpi

I've got a WinForms application that brings in an image into a picturebox and I allow the user to click on the control to add a "stamp" at that point on the image. When the user is finished, each "stamp" location is stored in an XML for use elsewhere in the application where the stamps are redrawn (as to not alter the original image) in the locations specified beforehand.

Now, my problem is that these locations are in terms of pixels and originally I noticed that certain computers would display the redrawn "stamps" differently than the original computer. I did a little research and found that the DPI settings could help solve this issue. So, I've tried adding code to offset this issue, but it doesn't appear to be working correctly. Here are my steps:

- When the form initializes, I grab the  current computer's DPI using `Me.CreateGraphics().DpiX` and `Me.CreateGraphics().DpiY`. I also grab the original computer's graphics stored in the XML file
- For each "stamp" stored in the XML file, I set the desired location in a `Point` variable by using a similar calculation as this:
  `New Point(Stamp.X * (dpiX / dpoX), Stamp.Y * (dpiY / dpoY))` where `dpi?` is the current computer and `dpo?` is the original computer

Am I going at this the right way, or is there an easier way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Have you declared the application to DPI aware so that it gets to true DPI values.  See: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#high_dpi_tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#high_dpi_tutorial).

Comment: The directions appear to be more focused for WPF than WinForms. The closest I've found is a series of AutoSize settings on the forms themselves to make the form "DPI aware". However, I think I resolved the issue. I believe I was missing the conversion from string to integer while grabbing the ratio's from the XML file.